# Why is my animation not working with Framer-motion, React and Fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fullpage.js, framer-motion

I'm trying to do animation with Framer motion and React.js + Fullpage.js, but it doesn't do the animation when it goes down. I need help to animate everytime it switches section

Here's the result right but it should animate once user go visit a section(https://wg2qk5-3000.csb.app/#22)

Here's my code

**React fullpage wrapper**

```
'use client'
import './globals.css'
import { Poppins } from 'next/font/google'
import ReactFullpage from "@fullpage/react-fullpage";
import React from 'react';
const poppins = Poppins({weight: "400", subsets: ["latin"] });



export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  })
{
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={poppins.className}>          <ReactFullpage
            navigation
            showActiveTooltip
            scrollOverflow={true}
            verticalCentered={true}
            anchors={['11', '22', '33', '44', '55']}
            onLeave={(origin, destination, direction) =>
              {
                console.log("onLeave event", { origin, destination, direction });
                console.log(destination.anchor);
              }}
              render={({ state, fullpageApi, origin, destination, direction }) =>
              {
                return (
                  <>
                    <>
                      {children}
                    </>
                </>
              );
            }}
          />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**My sections aka {children}**

```
"use client";
import * as React from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

export default function Sections()
{
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <div className="section">
        <motion.h1
          initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
        >
          111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
        </motion.h1>
      </div>
      <div className="section">
        <motion.h1
          initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
        >
          22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
        </motion.h1>
      </div>
      <div className="section">
        <motion.h1
          initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
        >
          3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
        </motion.h1>
      </div>
      <div className="section">
        <motion.h1
          initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
        >
          444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
        </motion.h1>
      </div>
      <div className="section">
        <motion.h1
          initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0, y: -50 }} 
        >
          55555555555555555555555555555555555555
        </motion.h1>
      </div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the animations or the library you use for the animations is scroll-based, you'll need to enable the scroll bar on fullPage.js by using the fullPage.js option `scrollBar:true`.

The other option is using fullPage.js callbacks such as [onLeave](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/docs/#onleave-origin-destination-direction-trigger) or [afterLoad](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/docs/#afterload-origin-destination-direction-trigger) to trigger them yourself.